# Resolving Duplicate sources.list entry for apt

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

We apparently have conflicting apt repository entries:

```
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 902650 902658
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_universe_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 439722 439727
W: Duplicate sources.list entry https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/  Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.bintray.com_sbt_debian_Packages.gz)
```

Our /etc/apt/sources.list is here:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'universe'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
```

I do not see the specific entries that are mentioned in the errors. Tips appreciated.   We are on 14.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a different file that had duplicates `/etc/apt/source.list.d/sbt.list`

```
 deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /
 deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /
```

One of the dup's was removed and the warning went away.